# Novice seeking help, Max Aggregate not returning expected results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm still very new to MS-SQL. I have a simple table and query that that is getting the best of me. I know it will something fundamental I'm overlooking.

I've changed the field names but the idea is the same.
So the idea is that every time someone signs up they get a RegID, Name, and Team. The names are unique, so for below yes John changed teams. And that's my trouble.

```
            Football Table
+------------+----------+---------+
| Max_RegID  |   Name   |   Team  |
+------------+----------+---------+
|   100      |   John   |   Red   |
|   101      |   Bill   |   Blue  |
|   102      |   Tom    |   Green |
|   103      |   John   |   Green |
+------------+----------+---------+
```

With the query at the bottom using the Max_RegID, I was expecting to get back only one record.

```
+------------+----------+---------+
| Max_RegID  |   Name   |   Team  |
+------------+----------+---------+
|   103      |   John   |   Green |
+------------+----------+---------+
```

Instead I get back below, Which seems to include Max_RegID but also for each team. What am I doing wrong?

```
+------------+----------+---------+
| Max_RegID  |   Name   |   Team  |
+------------+----------+---------+
|   100      |   John   |   Red   |
|   103      |   John   |   Green |
+------------+----------+---------+
```

My Query

```
SELECT
  Max(Football.RegID) AS Max_RegID,
  Football.Name,
  Football.Team
FROM
  Football    
GROUP BY
  Football.RegID,
  Football.Name,
  Football.Team
```

EDIT* Removed the WHERE statement

Comment: Where regid = max .... Or select top 1 order by regid desc

Comment: `The names are unique`  .. but you have 2 Jhons ...

Comment: Thanks to everyone, In my effort to make my question easier, I ended up asking the wrong question. What would I need to do if I didn't have the WHERE statement.

Comment: In explanation of your query: If you `group by` every column then you will get back every row (assuming that `Max_RegId` is unique, e.g. an `identity` column). Generally you group by one or more columns that have repeating values, e.g. `Name`, in order to summarize the data for each value. Tip: If you include the table schema then we don't have to guess at data types, identity columns, ... .

Comment: So now you want the maxId for each name instead of only Jhon?

Comment: The intent is to show the highest RegID for each name, and to show what the Team is. Even if different players change teams and have multiple RegIDs. As far grouping since i'm using Max for the RegID I have to include all columns or it errors on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting the results that you are is because of the way you have your `GROUP BY` clause structured.

When you're using any aggregate function, `MAX(X)`, `SUM(X)`, `COUNT(X)`, or what have you, you're telling the SQL engine that you want the aggregate value of column X for each unique combination of the columns listed in the `GROUP BY` clause.

In your query as written, you're grouping by all three of the columns in the table, telling the SQL engine that each tuple is unique. Therefore the query is returning ALL of the values, and you aren't actually getting the `MAX` of anything at all.

What you actually want in your results is the maximum RegID for each distinct value in the `Name` column and also the `Team` that goes along with that (`RegID`,`Name`) combination.

To accomplish that you need to find the `MAX(ID)` for each `Name` in an initial data set, and then use that list of `RegID`s to add the values for `Name` and  `Team` in a secondary data set.

*Caveat* (per comments from @HABO): This is premised on the assumption that RegID is a unique number (an `IDENTITY` column, value from a `SEQUENCE`, or something of that sort). If there are duplicate values, this will fail.

The most straight forward way to accomplish that is with a sub-query. The sub-query below gets your unique `RegID`s, then joins to the original table to add the other values.

```
SELECT
  f.RegID
 ,f.Name
 ,f.Team
FROM
  Football AS f
  JOIN
    (--The sub-query, sq, gets the list of IDs
      SELECT
        MAX(f2.RegID) AS Max_RegID
      FROM
        Football AS f2
      GROUP BY
        f2.Name
    ) AS sq
      ON
      sq.Max_RegID = f.RegID;
```

EDIT: Sorry. I just re-read the question. To get just the single record for the `MAX(RegID)`, just take the `GROUP BY` out of the sub-query, and you'll just get the current maximum value, which you can use to find the values in the rest of the columns.

```
SELECT
  f.RegID
 ,f.Name
 ,f.Team
FROM
  Football AS f
  JOIN
    (--The sub-query, sq, now gets the MAX ID
      SELECT
        MAX(f2.RegID) AS Max_RegID
      FROM
        Football AS f2
    ) AS sq
      ON
      sq.Max_RegID = f.RegID;
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who contributed. I always feel like like i'm trying to light a cigarette with a rocket engine when I ask questions here, but you guys always know how to respond that makes it easy to understand.

Comment: Great explanation with the caveat that it is based on the assumption that `RegId` is unique, e.g. an identity column. While likely, the OP has chosen to maintain _plausible deniability_ about that. Still worthy of an upvote.

Comment: @HABO, thanks, and your caveat is worth noting, which I did in an edit just now.

Answer (score 0):

Use row_number()

```
    select * from 
(SELECT
      Football.RegID AS Max_RegID,
      Football.Name,
      Football.Team, row_number() over(partition by name order by Football.RegID desc) as rn
    FROM
      Football
    WHERE
      Football.Name = 'John')a
where rn=1
```

Comment: After OP comment, he want this but without where

Answer (score 0):

You need `self` join :

```
select f1.*
from Football f inner join
     Football f1 
     on f1.name = f.name
where f.Max_RegID = 103;
```

After re-visit question, the sample data suggests me subquery :

```
select f.*
from Football f
where name = (select top (1) f1.name
              from Football f1
              order by f1.Max_RegID desc
             );
```

Comment: is there any necessary of inner join after giving where condition =103

Comment: if you filter with 103 then how it can be maximum, you just consider a static value here

Comment: do you really need sub-query in this way for this answer??

Answer (score 0):

simply you can edit your query below way

```
SELECT *      
FROM
  Football f
WHERE
  f.Name = 'John' and 
 Max_RegID = (SELECT  Max(Football.Max_RegID) where Football.Name = 'John'
         )
```

or
if sql server simply use this

```
select top 1 * from Football f
where f.Name = 'John'
order by Max_RegID desc
```

or
if mysql then

```
select  * from Football f
    where f.Name = 'John'
    order by Max_RegID desc
Limit 1
```

Comment: In your first solution there is no need to check for "John" in the outer query. The subquery has already filtered by `Name`.

Comment: @HABO lets put another id with different name what will be the max id in that case, i consider that also

Comment: If you added `( 104, 'Cindy', 'Paisley' )` then the subquery will filter it out since it doesn't match `where Football.Name = 'John'`. Checking again for "John" in the outer query still seems redundant _if we assume that `MaxRegId` is unique_.